# input from a tablet to asp.net # application

Tags: c#, asp.net, tablet-pc

I was wondering if I can capture tablets input to asp.net C#(web application). I mean if I write something on the tablets screen(E.G : Hi, How Are you) can I get it in a string format that I can manipulate, like enter it in the database and etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ofcourse you can. You're not making a joke, are you? (just making 30 chars)

Comment: din get you. Can you provide me with some links that can guide me through.

Comment: You would need to know how to build websites using ASP.Net .. Umm may be begin with [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/)

Comment: I am familiar with building website with an exp of 1+ years. But have never worked where I can take tablets input in asp.net web application.

Comment: What do you mean by "tablets input"? A website is a website whether you look at it in a tablet or a laptop.

Comment: I mean, say suppose I am writing a story on my tablet keeping it connected to my application which is running on a PC. When I type in something or write something using stylus the written part should get converted to a string and get stored in database through my web application.

Comment: Writing a story where? Are you opening a browser in your tablet & going to your website & writing it there? Or, are you writing your story in a notepad app in your tablet?

Comment: Yes, writing something in a notepad app of my file.

Comment: Then you cannot put it automatically in a database without you manually uploading/copy pasting the contents of the file somewhere to your application. G2G.